# when don't keep activities selected on Setting , progress dialog is not dismissing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-preferences, android-progressbar

when "don't keep activities" is selected on Setting's Developer Options progress dialog is not dismissing.
Actually, I am displaying the Progerss bar,for initialize the Application, When I am going to Activity A to Activity B and then came to Activity A, the Progress bar is not dismissing after initialize completed. 
Below is my Code,

First Activity

```
package com.example.donotkeepactivitiesalive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int MESSAGE_PROGRESS_BAR_INITIALIZING = 1;
    private Dialog m_cObjDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + "before InitializeEnvironment >>>>>>");
        new InitializeEnvironment().execute();
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + "after InitializeEnvironment >>>>>>");
        Button lb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        lb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent lIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(lIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        m_cObjDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        m_cObjDialog.setTitle("Initializing");
        ((ProgressDialog) m_cObjDialog).setMessage("Initializing the Application");
        m_cObjDialog.setCancelable(false);
        return m_cObjDialog;
    }


    class InitializeEnvironment extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            System.out.println(getClass().getName() + "onPreExecute >>>>>>");
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(MESSAGE_PROGRESS_BAR_INITIALIZING);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " doInBackground >>>>>>");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            dismissDialog(MESSAGE_PROGRESS_BAR_INITIALIZING);
            System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " onPostExecute >>>>>>");
        }
    }

}
```

Second Activity

```
package com.example.donotkeepactivitiesalive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Is there any way to track this problem and work even if "don't keep activities" is enabled

Comment: are you getting any error...???

Comment: what is InitializeData(); method...???

Comment: It is my local method, in this method I am retrieving data from Data base.

Comment: if it is getting data from data base then why are you using asynctask is it more data in size..??

Comment: Yes. And I debugged, it is invoking to onPostExecute() and log also showing as "after invalidateOptionsMenu called >>>>>>" on log cat

Comment: it mean your asynctask working properly...

Comment: now whats the problem...???

Comment: When I click on Back button from Activity B, It is calling the onCreate() method of Activity A again  and then it is showing the progress bar, but it is not dismissing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26641/discussion-between-tiru-and-salmankhan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, by checking the Bundle object is null or not.If the Bundle object is null then call the AsynTask class, else don't call,

```
if(null == savedInstanceState) {
        new InitializeEnvironment().execute();
    }
```

But make sure that your previous Activity is not overriding onActivityResult()